# How to update posh-git

Tags: git, powershell, posh-git

I have an old version of posh-git that I want to update (while trying to solve slow powershell start ups)

I've pulls latest from the repo and when I am trying to do `.\install.ps1` I get

```
It seems posh-git is already installed...
```

How do I update posh-git?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

All it does is look if the script is being sourced in your profile:

```
$profileLine = ". '$installDir\profile.example.ps1'"
if(Select-String -Path $PROFILE -Pattern $profileLine -Quiet -SimpleMatch) {
    Write-Host "It seems posh-git is already installed..."
    return
}
```

Since it seems to have the installDir as the folder from which you run the install script, merely upgrading the folder with the newer version of posh-git should give have updated the files already.

If you are not comfortable with that, just remove the line that sources the `profile.example.ps1` in your profile and run the install again :)

Comment: even better, no pesky uninstall scripts.. worked well, thanks :)

Answer (score 12):

If installed via PsGet, you can just run

```
Update-Module posh-git
```

Answer (score 4):

I had installed via PsGet, so I renamed the folder

`C:\Users\[myName]\Documents\WindowsPowerShell\Modules\posh-git`

and re-ran

`Install-Module posh-git`

It downloaded the latest but told me it was already installed, probably because I hadn't removed the lines from Microsoft.PowerShell_profile.ps1. That was all I needed, though.