# Git command: "WARNING: Could not find ssh-agent" Issue persist

Tags: github, ssh, jekyll, ssh-agent, git-shell

The problem occured after:

- When installed the **Jekyll SEO Plugin** with `bundle install`
- installing GEM `jekyll-sitemap 0.11.0`
- When added a GEMfile in source file `C:\Users\User\Documents\GitHub\PROJECT`

Other Issues:

When I request: Jekyll serve --watch

I get the following error:

[image]

I have applied guidelines from:

http://haacked.com/archive/2011/12/19/get-git-for-windows.aspx/
https://stackoverflow.com/a/24368751/7160844

but without succes.

So far i found the `ssh-agent.exe` in `C:\Users\user\Desktop\cmder\vendor\git-for-windows\usr\bin`

*I was planning to re install Jekyll, but will that suffice?*

*What are the options?*

**Edit #1**:

1. I applied bundle exec jekyll serve / bundle exec jekyll serve --watch

[image]

**Edit #2**:

Issue in _config.yml is solved, I can host locally again!

Yet I have to maintain the use of `bundle exec jekyll serve --watch` 
And `WARNING: Could not find ssh-agent` is still occuring.

[image]

Comment: edit: guidelines from https://github.com/dahlbyk/posh-git/issues/160

Comment: This has nothing to do with Jekyll. To solve the Jekyll issue, install Bundler and do as the error msg states: `Prepend bundle exec to your command` so  simply run Jekyll like so: `bundle exec jekyll serve`

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but that was the first thing I applied, without succes! I edit my Question with the result.

Comment: Your edit doesn't show the use of `bundle exec jekyll serve` Instead I see `jekyll serve --watch` But the edit shows a new error in your `_config.yml : line 6`

Comment: The issue on `_config.yml : line 6` solved and back to default.  `bundle exec jekyll serve` works. Thank you Ash.

Comment: Yet I have to maintain the use of `bundle exec jekyll serve --watch` 
And `WARNING: Could not find ssh-agent` is still occuring. Is this a danger to this project?

Comment: Its not a danger to the project, but without setting it, the traffic from/to your terminal will be non-secure.

Comment: Try this guide: http://guides.beanstalkapp.com/version-control/git-on-windows.html#installing-ssh-keys. Instead of pasting the generated key into Beanstalk interface, paste it into `[HOME]/.ssh/id_rsa`, where `[HOME]` refers to the location on your drive where Git saves its `.gitconfig` file.

Comment: Also refer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31813080/windows-10-ssh-keys